# FactoryGirl builds uninitialized object on first call, then works as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

Using:

- `factory_girl_rails v4.3.0`
- `rails v4.0.1`
- `rspec-rails v2.14.0`

My first call to `FactoryGirl.build` returns an object all `nil` attributes.  If I call it again, it builds the object as expected, per the factory definition.  Here's a pry session to demonstrate the aberrant behavior:

```
∴ rspec ./spec/controllers/admin/base_controller_spec.rb:10
Run options: include {:locations=>{"./spec/controllers/admin/base_controller_spec.rb"=>[10]}}

Frame number: 0/25

From: /Users/george/work/salescrm/spec/support/controller_helpers.rb @ line 3 ControllerHelpers#sign_in:

     2:   def sign_in(user_type = nil)
 =>  3: binding.pry
     4:     user = FactoryGirl.create(user_type) unless user_type.nil?
     5:
     6:     if user.nil?
     7:       request.env['warden'].stub(:authenticate!).
     8:         and_throw(:warden, {:scope => :user})
     9:       controller.stub :current_user => nil
    10:     else
    11:       request.env['warden'].stub :authenticate! => user
    12:       controller.stub :current_user => user
    13:     end
    14:   end

[1] salescrm(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1>) »  FactoryGirl::VERSION
=> "4.3.0"
[2] salescrm(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1>) »  user_type
=> :admin_user
[3] salescrm(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1>) »  FactoryGirl.build(user_type)
=> #<User:0x007fbc8e010d68> {
                      :id => nil,
                   :email => nil,
      :encrypted_password => "",
    :reset_password_token => nil,
  :reset_password_sent_at => nil,
     :remember_created_at => nil,
           :sign_in_count => 0,
      :current_sign_in_at => nil,
         :last_sign_in_at => nil,
      :current_sign_in_ip => nil,
         :last_sign_in_ip => nil,
              :created_at => nil,
              :updated_at => nil,
                :username => nil,
              :first_name => nil,
               :last_name => nil,
              :roles_mask => nil
}
[4] salescrm(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1>) »  FactoryGirl.build(user_type)
=> #<User:0x007fbc8533ac90> {
                      :id => nil,
                   :email => "jan@email.com",
      :encrypted_password => "$2a$04$ROK0DlxigvTmgXY.kNsdL.z3R15cbZM60UbDi4iIqMtX.C1g6Fiii",
    :reset_password_token => nil,
  :reset_password_sent_at => nil,
     :remember_created_at => nil,
           :sign_in_count => 0,
      :current_sign_in_at => nil,
         :last_sign_in_at => nil,
      :current_sign_in_ip => nil,
         :last_sign_in_ip => nil,
              :created_at => nil,
              :updated_at => nil,
                :username => "jan_blogs",
              :first_name => "Jan",
               :last_name => "Blogs",
              :roles_mask => 1
}
```

And the factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email 'joe@email.com'
    username 'joe_blogs'
    password 'my_password'
    first_name 'Joe'
    last_name 'Blogs'

    factory :admin_user do
      first_name 'Jan'
      email 'jan@email.com'
      username 'jan_blogs'
      password 'my_password'

      roles [:admin]
    end
  end
end
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or what's going on?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`FactoryGirl.build` will initialize a user object, but not save it, compared with `FactoryGirl.create` which will initialize and save the object to the (test) database.

Does your app require a unique email address for each user? The [factory_girl documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/wiki/Usage#sequences-and-associations) shows how to create a unique sequence which you could use for the email field of instances of your user model.

Comment: Yes, `FactoryGirl.build` is supposed to initialize the object per the definition, but that's my issue: it's not.  Look again at the pry session I posted.  You'll see a call to `FG.build` results in an uninitialized User object.

Comment: Hi George. I believe the issue is specific to your rails app. Without knowing more about it, I'd be guessing. I'm using the same versions of factory_girl and rails and not experiencing this issue. Perhaps you could generate a new rails app with factory_girl in the Gemfile and see if you can reproduce the issue in the new app.

Comment: @AndyAtkinson I've seen something similar. Here's the behavior: `FactoryGirl.build(:product)` is invalid, whereas `Product.new(FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:product))` is valid. The problem stems from a dependent model, in my case it was a `Department` that a product belongs to. It was *that* model that had the problem, not the `Product`. The error message is not very helpful here.

Comment: @twopoint718 that makes sense. Factory Girl tries to initialize or create a set of objects, traversing associations. If one of them fails validation or initialization, then the related objects won't initialize.